# Terraform with aws to select ami based on tag with sort

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-ami

I'm building a Terraform config and I'm stuck with a tricky ami selection. My CI builds AMIs and add `MyVersionTag` on it based on the current build of the app on the CI. I would like to select the AMI based on this tag sort by version (`X.Y.Z` format) to take the latest.

Here is my command line using `aws cli` to select the AMI I want to use:

```sh
aws ec2 describe-images --filters 'Name=tag-key,Values=MyVersionTag' --query 'reverse(sort_by(Images[].{TagValue:Tags|[0].Value,ImageId:ImageId},&TagValue))|[0].ImageId'
```

I'm searching a way to configure an EC2 instance with this AMI id. I see 2 possible ways (please correct me):

- `aws_instance` with pure AMI ID as text (result of a command line through variable)
- `aws_ami` with filters

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried `aws_ami`?

Comment: Yes with filters. But I'm not able to sort and pick the last one.

Comment: You can always use a `data "external" "my_ami" { ... }` to run the snippet within terraform and use its output.

Comment: Is it best practices? I thought it was the very last thing to do.

Comment: I would certainly prefer it over adding a new variable and since `aws_ami` cannot do it what else can you do.

Comment: Ok. So I have a solution. I'll add it below.   thanks for your advises guys.

Comment: Can you assume that x.y.z monotonically increases over time? Eg you won't publish `1.2.0` followed by `2.0.0` and then publish `1.2.1` later? If so you can just ignore the value of the tag and use `most_recent` in the AMI data source which greatly simplifies things.

Comment: I thought about that but if I have to maintain 2 versions in the same time (2.X and 3.Y) that won't work because 2.3 can be release after 3.1.

Comment: So how would you then access your `2.3` release? Your current process has no input for a major branch version that it can select based on so it would return the 3.1 release ahead of 2.3 in that case which just inverts your problem.

Comment: I've improved it with variable on the Terraform script. Since it's called from CI, main version is based on app changelog. `MyVersionTag` -> `%{main_version_variable}.*.*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally make is using `external` key word. Here is my solution:

```
# example.tf

resource "aws_instance" "my-instance" {
  ami = data.external.latest_ami.result.ImageId
  # Other config
}

data "external" "latest_ami" {
  program = ["sh", "latest_ami_id.sh"]
  # Or simply
  program = ["aws", "ec2", "describe-images", "--filters", "Name=tag-key,Values=MyVersionTag", "--query", "reverse(sort_by(Images[].{TagValue:Tags|[0].Value,ImageId:ImageId},&TagValue))|[0].ImageId"]
}
```

```sh
# latest_ami_id.sh

#!/bin/bash

# It returns a json with following keys :
#. ImageId, Description, Tags (version actually)
aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=tag-key,Values=SecretCore" --query 'reverse(sort_by(Images[].{TagValue:Tags|[0].Value,ImageId:ImageId},&TagValue))|[0].ImageId'
```

Hope it will help someone else.

Comment: No need for the script file. you can just use `program = ["aws", "ec2", "describe-images", "--filters", "Name=tag-key,Values= MyVersionTag", "--query", "Images[].{Tags:Tags|[0].Value,ImageId:ImageId,Description:Description}|[0]"]`.

Comment: I've added your version too. Thanks!

Comment: The second version is particularly nice if you start adding some variables as input to the command :)

Comment: 100% true. I may use it myself with some custom versions I have in mind. 
For example the tag name could be a variable.. Easy to change. Easy to review. Better.

Comment: @luk2302 I've updated the command line. The previous one was not correct.

Answer (score 0):

i was try with your command but i got the error,

```
Error: Unexpected External Program Results
│
│   with data.external.latest_ami,
│   on main.tf line 25, in data "external" "latest_ami":
│   25:   program = ["sh", "latest_ami.sh"]
│
│ The data source received unexpected results after executing the program.
│
│ Program output must be a JSON encoded map of string keys and string values.
│
│ If the error is unclear, the output can be viewed by enabling Terraform's logging at TRACE level. Terraform documentation on logging:
│ https://www.terraform.io/internals/debugging
│
│ Program: /usr/bin/sh
│ Result Error: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]string
```

it's my main.tf

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = data.external.latest_ami.result.ImageId
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
}

data "external" "latest_ami" {
  program = ["sh", "latest_ami.sh"]
}
```

and here my latest_ami.sh

```
#latest_ami_id.sh
#!/bin/bash

# It returns a json with following keys :
#. ImageId, Description, Tags (version actually)
aws ec2 describe-images --filters 'Name=name,Values=packer-2022-04-06' --query 'reverse(sort_by(Images[].{TagValue:Tags|[0].Value,ImageId:ImageId},&TagValue))|[0].ImageId'
```

if i try running `./latest_ami.sh` it's work

```
"ami-xxxxxxx"
```